# Надо определить, есть ли в строковой переменной "sars-cov-2"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я не могу понять, почему мой код не работает

```
a = input()
s=1
f=11

while a[s:f]=="sars-cov-2":
    s+=1
    f+=1
if a[s:f]=="sars-cov-2":
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Возможно не работает из-за того, что строка начинается с индекса 0, а вы начинаете искать начиная с индекса 1. Проще проверять с помощью оператора `in`: `if "sars-cov-2" in a: print("YES")`

Answer (score 2):

Наличие подстроки в строке проще проверить с помощью оператора `in`:

```
a = input()

if "sars-cov-2" in a:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Если нужно определить, с какого индекса начинается подстрока, можно использовать метод `find`:

```
a = input()

i = a.find("sars-cov-2")    
if i != -1:
    print("Yes, starting from index", i)
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Вместо `if i!=-1` можно использовать `if ~i` :)

Comment: @Евгений, если есть желание "вымахнуться", то можно. А если нужно писать понятный, читаемый код, то не стоит.

Comment: Ну, в данной ситуации - согласен, а вот `while ~a.find(a)` - вполне неплохой подход для прохода по всем вхождениям. Потому знать об этом тоже может быть полезно

Comment: @Евгений, и в вашем примере тоже нет смысла использовать битовое отрицание. Это точно такое же "смотрите как я могу" в ущерб понятности кода. Знать об этом полезно, но писать так не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно написать в while обратное условие. И искать с нулевого символа. Хотя это и не оптимальный способ поиска подстроки в любом случае:

```
a = input()
s=0
f=10

while a[s:f]!="sars-cov-2":
    s+=1
    f+=1
if a[s:f]=="sars-cov-2":
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```